# Timeout in ActiveMQ AMQP example code

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp

I'm trying to get started with ActiveMQ and I ran the example code. It boils down to this:

```
JmsConnectionFactory factory = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:=5672");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection(user, password);
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
destination = session.createQueue("change");
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

while (true) {
    Message msg = consumer.receive();
    «process»
}
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/assembly/src/release/examples/amqp/java/src/main/java/example/Listener.java)

It works fine, but if I don't send messages for a minute or two I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException:
Transport closed due to the peer exceeding our requested idle-timeout
```

I don't know how often I expect to get messages (could be hundreds a second, could be one a day).

1. Is there some configuration option that I need to set so there is never a time-out?
2. What's the right way to write a client? Is there a good reason the default has a timeout that means I shouldn't use this method?

Blocking polling like this is fine for me.

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.11.2. I'm running the server with `activemq console` and using whatever default configuration ships.

Comment: What broker and versions are you using, not enough info to help

Comment: Sorry. Latest everything. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ActiveMQ version of 5.12.0+ in order for the client to not time out as the earlier broker versions didn't support AMQP heartbeats so the client is not getting what it asked for from the broker.  Support for heartbeats was added under [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5757) issue.

Prior to version 5.12.0 of ActiveMQ the AMQP support was still in a developmental state and not recommended for production use.  The code has undergone a lot of testing and the latest broker release (5.13.2) is very stable when used with Qpid JMS.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that the current release is buggy?

Comment: The current release is 5.13.2 and you say you are using 5.11.2 so it depends on your definition of current.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I realised I'm using a package manager (brew). What I really meant was "is the demo code in the example meant to work out of the box or not, and is that true of 5.13.2?". Sounds like the answer is "yes and no"?

Comment: As stated, if you use a client that requests heartbeats then you need to use a later release, or disable the heartbeat functionality on the client so it won't time out the connection when idle.